# How to write unit test for HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, moq, vs-unit-testing-framework

Below is an Example.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/api/mycontroller")]
    [HttpGet]
    public int ID()
    {
        try
        {
            return somecontroller.getID(ID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Above it the controller that is fetching the ID from the below controller. 
Below is the controller that it is inherited.

```
public class Controller : ApiController
{
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["ID"]);
        }
    }
}
```

How do i write unit test case for the following.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, unit testing `HttpContext.Current`. That's one of my favorites :-)

You can't write a unit test for something that depends on `HttpContext.Current`. So if you want to write testable code the first step is to search in your entire solution for the `HttpContext.Current` keyword and simply wipe them out from existence.

In this particular case you would of course replace them with the corresponding abstraction:

```
public class Controller : ApiController
{
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(Request.Headers.GetValues("ID").FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's completely trivial to unit test your Web API controller properly:

```
// arrange
var sut = new MyController();
sut.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
sut.Request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("ID", "5");


// act
var actual = sut.SomeControllerAction();

// assert
Assert.AreEqual(5, actual);
```

Comment: Thanks Darin for the quick reply. Appricate it. Does not slove the problem
("ID").FirstOrDefault does not work. Says does not contain definition. :(

Comment: Well, hard to say what you might have done wrong. This has worked for me perfectly fine.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It is possible to unit test with HttpContext, just set  HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", "http://www.example.com", ""), new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())); and you can get it from the code.(Your answer is correct, just want to clarify it's possible and sometimes useful)